# How to handle and do multiple requests for Multiple page response JSON

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am looking help probably pseudo code will do.

Example I have

```
{
    success: true, //boolean, shows if operation succeeded (similar to HTTP status)
    data: null, //object in other cases
    additional_data: {
        pagination: { //for endpoints that list data
            start: 0,
            limit: 100,
            more_items_in_collection: false
        }
    }
}
```

**Now if i have more items in pagination and 'more_items_in_collection' is true, how do i write a logic to send request again and get next page data. i can't think through. i'm using python 'requests' just in case.**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```html
for a in ['additional_data']['pagination']:
         print(#the data you want from pagination)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do your API return next page URI?

If yes: you will have to create a next page URL using that.

Thanks,